# Homework: Simulating coin tosses until consecutive heads using R

Tags: r, matlab, probability

I am new to R hence asking here (haven't been able to find very helpful tutorials for simulation that are detailed.)

The problem statement is this

1. Simulate a coin toss for 20 times and record the number of heads
   & longest run of heads.
2. Simulate a coin toss and record the number of flips necessary until 2,3,4 heads occur in sequence (consecutively) (negative binomial?)
3. Make 100 runs with different seeds to find the distribution of items recorded.

How does one go about solving this in the programming language R ?

For 1, I did the following:

```
n=20                #no of trials
y=NULL              #initializing a vector of NULL values   
for (i in 1:n) {
    x=runif(1)      #random uniform
    if (x<0.5) {    #if condition for assigning heads / tails
        y[i]='H'
    } else {
       y[i]='T'
    }
}
y                   #print the vector storing the heads and tails.
```

For 2, I understand that this is a case of negative binomial because it says "until 2,3,4 heads occur in sequence" . But I am not sure how to proceed to write the code in R or come up with the logic.

For 3, I am guessing have to calculate the number of heads got in 100 runs, run lengths of heads. But what does it imply to set *different seeds*? I am unsure of that.

**note** This is a homework problem, yes (I am not able to tag it so). I do not need the code, just some pointers/ corrections/clarifications/suggestions would help.

**edit** For simulating 2, I tried out the following code on MATLAB -

```
head_count = 0;
flip_count = 0;

while (head_count < 3)                  #counting for 3 multiple heads
    flip = rand(1);
    flip_count = flip_count+1;
    if (flip > 0.5)
        head_count = head_count + 1;
    else 
         head_count = 0;       #invalidate head counts if not successive.
    end
end
disp(flip_count)
```

Please let me know if this logic is correct. And I can recreate it using R.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please identify it as such.  Also, please share what you have tried so far rather than just asking folks to write your code and do your work for you...

Comment: Raaj, as Justin said, on Stack Overflow, we prefer that you post what you have tried so far and mention if it is a homework. The process of trying is as useful as the solution.

Comment: @Raaj i would give ?rbinom a read

Comment: Some hints! `set.seed`, `x <- sample(c("H","T"),20,replace=T)` and `rle(x)`.

Comment: Agree with @Raaj, `set.seed(1); tosses = rbinom(20,1,0.5)`

Comment: @MartínBel i did use it initially but I am to use a logic and show it through the code hence I cannot use rbinom. Thanks a lot for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is homework, I would like to give you some pointers for #2 and #3.

For #2, make a loop which keeps doing coin tosses and count the number of heads in a row. At every toss increase the count of tosses by 1 and when reaching the number of heads requested, just return the count of tosses.

To get you started, this will do nbTosses tossesL

```
coin <- c('h','t')

ComputeNbTosses <- function(targetTosses) {
  nbtosses = 0;
  while (nbtosses < targetTosses) {
    nbtosses = nbtosses + 1
  }
  return(nbtosses);
}
```

You just need to amend it to take in parameter targetHeads and exit the while loop only when you have reached the tagetHeads.

For #3, put #2 in a function and then use `set.seed(integer)`, to set the seed. Random numbers on a computer are not really random. Most of random generators allow you to set a seed. If you use the same seed you will get twice the same sequence of pseudo random numbers, this allows for debugging.

EDIT: I changed #2 from a recursion to a normal loop, it will be easier to code for him.

EDIT (Tip):
This will count how many heads in a row you have, now you have to make the loop stop when you reach the target value of heads:

```
coin <- c('h','t')

ComputeNbTosses <- function(targetTosses) {
  nbTosses = 0;
  nbHeadsInRow = 0;
  allTosses = c();
  while (nbTosses < targetTosses) {
    toss = sample(coin,1,T)
    allTosses = c(allTosses, toss);
    if (toss == 'h') {
      nbHeadsInRow = nbHeadsInRow + 1;
    } else {
       nbHeadsInRow = 0;
    }
    nbTosses = nbTosses + 1
  }
  ret = list();
  ret$nbTosses = nbTosses;
  ret$nbHeadsInRowAtEnd = nbHeadsInRow;
  ret$allTosses = allTosses;
  return(ret);
} 

ComputeNbTosses(5);
ComputeNbTosses(8);
```

This will print how many heads in row you had when it reached nbTosses. This is not what you want. What you want is:

- change the argument from `targetTosses` to `targetHeadsInRow`
- change the condition in the `while` so that it stops when `nbHeadsInRow` reaches `targetHeadsInRow`.
- what you need to return is `nbTosses` (the number of tosses to reach your condition)

Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Thank you for this.

For 2) I thought of putting the code I have written inside a while loop, and count the heads as well. However, I am hitting a block when I have to figure out a way of counting **successive heads** and not simply heads. 

Maybe I should code it in MATLAB first since I am familiar with it and can ask for help here to convert it into R? That seems like a fair question to ask.

Comment: I will give you another tip